# Ondas em cordas com CSS

Tags: html, css

Olá, preciso de ondas em cordas, especie de ondas magnéticas, apenas com CSS. Vi alguns exemplos e nenhum era como eu gostaria, também não consegui adaptar para a forma que quero. Se alguém poder me ajudar agradeço!

Segue o exemplo na imagem da como eu preciso que seja:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: E por que você precisa fazer isso somente com CSS?

Comment: Pode ser um SVG? Com CSS só daria pra fazer na base da gambiarra, não seria um modelo aplicável

Comment: Para facilitar a implementação. Sim pode ser em SVG!

Answer (score 1):

Vamos por passos, como vc falou que SVG é uma alternativa vou te dar um passo a passo de como entender e usar. Logicamente vc vai ter que ler alguma documentação.

Documentação da Mozilla sobre `<path>` no SVG: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths

> Existem três comandos diferentes que você pode usar para criar curvas
>   suaves. Duas dessas curvas são curvas de Bézier e a terceira é um
>   "arco" ou parte de um círculo. ... Há um número infinito de curvas de Bezier, mas apenas duas simples estão disponíveis em elementos de caminho: um cúbico, chamado com C, e um quadrático, chamado com Q.
>
> A curva cúbica, C, é a curva um pouco mais complexa. Beziers cúbicos
>   recebem dois pontos de controle para cada ponto. Portanto, para criar
>   um Bezier cúbico, você precisa especificar três conjuntos de
>   coordenadas.

```
Cx1 y1, x2 y2, xy (ou c dx1 dy1, dx2 dy2, dx dy)
```

Exemplo básico de *Curvede Path* correspondente a imagem. Repare que a cor é no `stroke` e não no `fill`, pois é um *Path* Cada um desses pontos vermelhos no final das linhas retas significa um "anchor point" (ponto ancora), vc vai movimenta-lo no eixo X Y individualmente para criar suas curvas.

[Aqui tem um simulador simples pra vc brincar com esses `anchor points`](https://codepen.io/explosion/pen/YGApwd)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<svg width="190" height="160" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="background-color: blue;">
  <path d="M10 80 C 40 10, 65 10, 95 80 S 150 150, 180 80" stroke="white" fill="transparent"/>

  <path d="M10 50 C 20 20, 60 20, 95 80 S 160 160, 180 50" stroke="white" style="stroke-opacity: .3; " fill="transparent"/>
</svg>
```

Artigos para vc ler mais sobre o assunto, eles são bem didático, porem estão em inglês:

- https://vanseodesign.com/web-design/svg-paths-curve-commands/
- https://css-tricks.com/svg-path-syntax-illustrated-guide/

**DICA:** Vc pode usar softwares como Adobe Illustrator ou Corel para criar seus Paths e depois exporta-los como SVG, ou então usar ferramentas on-line, eu indico o Figma. Ou se preferir logicamente vc pode fazer na mão...

Comment: Muito bom!! Me ajudou bastante, muito obrigado pela solução e explicação.

Comment: @SulivanSantos legal que te deu uma luz e te ajudou ai. Se a minha resposta te serviu considere marca-la como Resposta "Aceita" nesse ícone `✔` logo abaixo das Setinhas ao lado da minha resposta.